# Grab a URL from browser and append

Tags: vb.net, url, browser

I am trying to help out a disabled lady who likes to do jigsaw puzzles, we use https://thejigsawpuzzles.com/.  She doesn't have good mobility in her hand and fingers.  She can only do the 20 piece puzzles, however most have a lot more pieces, she finds it hard to select "Change Cut" then choose classic then 20 pieces.  I was thinking of a simple form with a reasonably large button that would get the url from the browser (firefox) and add a piece to the end "?cutout=20classic" and then refresh the site.  I'm not sure how to code such a thing though.  I even emailed the site owner if they could have an option in the account to always choose a 20 piece puzzle he said it's a good idea but nothing happened.  I use Visual Studio 2022 Community and have made basic programs with VB.NET but anything appreciated

Thanks

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Discover Windows accessibility features](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/discover-windows-accessibility-features-8b1068e6-d3b8-4ba8-b027-133dd8911df9)

Comment: The [Redirector add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/redirector/) for Firefox might be of use.

Comment: I spent a few hours looking at browser extensions, a few came close like append to domain, which would append the text I need after the .com domain, rather than right at the end of the URL.  There was another one for proxy servers that could do the same thing.  The others I couldn't figure out how to work or they didn't work the way I needed for example the URL redirector addons.